# compare the bunch of strings from a given line in python

Tags: python-2.7

How I can check if the strings

```
"1-1374729743 -H 192.168.26.15 -p movik123 executed status:(success)"
```

is present in

```
"DBG:1:(0){07/25/13 - 01:29:23:011145}:ExportFWWorkerThread.cpp:156:handleExport VERTICA: cmd - /opt/daf/bin/vertica-export.py -f "*t1*,*t1.mon,*t2*,*t2.mon" -s /data/Dellraid6-ppe/export/1-1374729743 -H 192.168.26.15 -p movik123 executed status:(success) updated bitmask:(0)"
```

using python

Comment: 1. can you show your code? 2. can you tidy up your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently on a unix like system and grep could be an alternative to python for this, if you are new to python :-

```
grep PATTERN [FILE...]
```